# Digits of $\pi$ forming primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $f(n)$ be the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ . How many times is $f(n)$ prime on the interval $[1, k]$ ? Are there infinitely many prime $f(n)$'s on $[1, \infty)$?

I know this is probably be a very hard question and most likely an open problem, but I am just curious.

Comment: If your curious about this, look [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiDigits.html) until you receive an answer :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nothing is known for sure, because not much is known about the digit distribution of $\pi$. For instance it is not known known whether $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number), but it is (weakly) believed to be, because $\pi$ has no reason not to be (and tests on the first few millions of digits don't say anything to the contrary), and it is known at [almost all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_all) real numbers are normal. So let's assume that the digits of $\pi$ do indeed appear uniformly at random, and see what that might imply.

There is a popular heuristic, based on the [prime number theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem), that a random number with $n$ digits has "probability" $\frac{1}{n \ln 10}$ of being prime. So, by this heuristic, the expected number of times $f(n)$ — the number formed by the first $n$ digits of $\pi$ -- is prime, for $1 \le n \le k$, is
$$\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{n \ln 10} = \frac{H_k}{\ln 10},$$
where $H_k$ is the $k$th [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). As $H_k \sim \ln k$, which (very slowly) goes to $\infty$ as $k \to \infty$, this means that yes, we do expect (based on heuristic) that there are infinitely many $n$ such that $f(n)$ is prime.

Actual calculation has revealed (see [OEIS A060421](http://oeis.org/A060421) and [OEIS A005042](http://oeis.org/A005042)) that $f(n)$ is prime for $n$ in the list (so far)
$$1, 2, 6, 38, 16208, 47577, 78073,$$
the corresponding primes being (listing only the first four)
$$3, 31, 314159, 31415926535897932384626433832795028841, \dots$$

This is roughly consistent with the heuristics, though we found primes slightly earlier. See [this page by Kevin Brown](http://oeis.org/A060421/a060421.htm) for discussion.